# Can't bring up network interface - RTNETLINK answers: Operation already in progress

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, network-interface

I have Kali Linux 2020.2 on my laptop. When I started it today I couldn't connect to any wifi networks. I checked the network manager:

```
systemctl status network-manager.service 
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-04-24 16:11:21 MDT; 2min 21s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1709 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18802)
     Memory: 3.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1709 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Apr 24 16:12:36 kali NetworkManager[1709]: <warn>  [1587766356.8333] device (wlan0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
Apr 24 16:12:41 kali NetworkManager[1709]: <error> [1587766361.0602] device (wlan0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Apr 24 16:12:41 kali NetworkManager[1709]: <info>  [1587766361.0602] device (wlan0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

So I checked the status of wpa_supplicant:

```
systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service 
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-04-24 16:06:48 MDT; 7min ago
   Main PID: 1581 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18802)
     Memory: 1.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
             └─1581 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

Apr 24 16:12:24 kali wpa_supplicant[1581]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Apr 24 16:12:27 kali wpa_supplicant[1581]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Operation already in progress
Apr 24 16:12:27 kali wpa_supplicant[1581]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Apr 24 16:12:27 kali wpa_supplicant[1581]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

I then checked my network interfaces and sure enough, wlan0 is down:

```
ip a
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:be:3d:a1:54:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I tried bringing up wlan0 manually and I got this message:

```
ip link set wlan0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation already in progress
```

If anyone knows what causes this or how to fix it that would be great, thanks!

Comment: I am also facing same issue. In Journalctl I am getting "device (wlan0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.wpa_suupplicant1.Unknown"

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo dmesg` (only relevant portions please)?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo iwconfig wlan0 down` and then `up` instead of `down` to get it back up? What does that output?

Comment: May this link help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/630576/iwlist-set-essid-operation-already-in-progress